# Combining multiple values into one cell based off two criteria

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I have a data dump in Excel that consists of monthly crew member hours worked data. Currently, there are multiple rows of data for the same date.

[image: Excel Snapshot]

```
1128057 ALC - D GRAY    ALCCOM  LM  FM  6/3/2019    1    
1128057 ALC - D GRAY    ALCCOM  LM  FM  6/3/2019    3    
1128057 ALC - D GRAY    ALCCOM  LM  FM  6/3/2019    5
```

This guy times out at different times so I want it to read

```
ALC - D GRAY   ALCCOM  LM FM 6/3/2019 9
```

There are 3 unique crew members names and every date of the month. So ideally, all of the hours on each day need to be combined for each crew member. It would be great if it was exported as a report to a different sheet. Below is what I have so far.

```
Sub Relamp()
'define variables
Dim RowNum As Long, LastRow As Long
'turn off screen updating.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'start below titles and make full selection of data
RowNum = 2
LastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Range("A2", Cells(LastRow, 8)).Select
'for loop for all rows in selection with cells.
For Each Row In Selection
With Cells
'if crew members name matches
If Cells(RowNum, 2) = Cells(RowNum + 1, 2) Then
    'if date matches
    If Cells(RowNum, 6) = Cells(RowNum + 1, 6) Then
        'combine values
        Cells(RowNum + 1, 7).Copy Destination:=Cells(RowNum, 7)


End Sub
```

This code is not complete, kind of stuck at the moment

Comment: You're missing a significant portion of your code - where are your closing `End If`s, `End With` and `Next Row`? This code as it stands would fail to compile.

Comment: I want the hours to be combined, for each unique date and then delete the duplicate rows, wouldnt that be a FOR loop?

Comment: @JohnnyHarley, here is what you do: in the new sheet, copy and paste the data, then delete duplicates based on the other columns. Then for the hours column, use a `SUMIFS` based on data in the first sheet. If you still have issues, then let me know

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use VBA in order to achieve this. You can get the desired result by creating a Pivot Table. Add Number, Alpha Name, Union Code,Job Type, Job Step and Work Date as "Rows" and Sum of Hours as a value field. Then go to the Pivot options, set it to "Classic View" and then remove the Total and Sub Total display fields. The result will look something like this

[image: Excel Pivot Table]